# Django how to define kwargs in a url pattern

Tags: django, django-urls

```
url(r'^employee/create/(?P<employee_type>[\w-]+)$',
    staff_member_required(EmployeeCreateView.as_view()),
    name='employee-create'),
```

I am using the above url config for following url:

```
<a href="{% url "myapp_app:employee-create" employee_type=product_eng %}" class="button is-light is-outlined">Create Product Engineer</a>
<a href="{% url "myapp_app:employee-create" employee_type=product_dev %}" class="button is-light is-outlined">Create Product Developer</a>
```

But this gives me an error saying matching reverse url is not found. How may I fix this issue?

Comment: Does ending your pattern with `/$` instead of `$` make a difference?

Comment: Are you sure (having printed them/output them to the webpage itself) that `product_eng` and `product_dev` contain only characters matching `[\w-]`?

Comment: @Evert If I add a trailing slash it will appear // in url

Comment: Sounds like your template variables are empty, if you see a double slash.

Comment: @Evert yes there will be letters only

Comment: Did you print the variables, or output them in the webpage?

Comment: Seems its working now, yes I did print variables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157530/discussion-between-kalanamith-and-evert).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to fix the url pattern, which is missing a slash, as pointed out by @Evert:

```
r'^employee/create/(?P<employee_type>[\w-]+)/$'
```

In your template you can call that url pattern as you have done it:

```
"{% url "myapp_app:employee-create" employee_type=product_eng %}"
```

Here it is important that `myapp_app` is the namespace, and `employee-create` the name of the url pattern.
From here we can't see whether you have this namespace specified.

For the part `employee_type=product_eng` is important that the variable `product_eng` actually exists in the template and holds a meaningful value.
You can simplify that by writing only:

```
"{% url "myapp_app:employee-create" product_eng %}"
```